# Svn: is it possible to merge multiple revisions into one?

Tags: svn

I have multiple svn revisions, but I want to merge them into one in the same branch (another branch also acceptable).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot merge multiple revisions into a single one with Subversion. You can try to merge a branch into itself but I don't think it'll work - you're just reapplying changes that already exist, so there will be nothing to commit.

However, you can merge a range of revisions made in one branch into another branch and *that* will result in a single revision being made to the "destination" branch (basically, you're saying "diff branch A from revision 123 to 456 and apply to branch B all at once"). This is a fairly standard mode of operating and [the official manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) describes the workflow.

Answer (score -1):

merge locally, then commit files.

Comment: What do you mean "merge locally" ?